# C - swapping two 2D arrays by switching pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I would like to swap two variables containing 2D arrays. I believe this can be simply done by swapping their pointers. I tried this code, but it does not work and I have no idea why, perhaps I am not understanding pointers correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int ***a, int ***b) {
    int ** temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[10][10];
    int b[10][10];

    a[1][5] = 4;
    b[1][5] = 2;

    printf("%d, %d\n", a[1][5], b[1][5]);

    swap(&b, &a);

    printf("%d, %d\n", a[1][5], b[1][5]);
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
4, 2
4, 2
```

I would expect it to output

```
4, 2
2, 4
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are stars in my eyes..  If you need a function to swap two pointers, you only need one star on the parameters, no matter what the target of the pointers is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` and `b` in `main` function are not pointers but arrays.
If you want to use pointers, use pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

void swap(int (**a)[N][N], int (**b)[N][N]) {
    int (*temp)[N][N] = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[N][N];
    int b[N][N];
    int (*pa)[N][N] = &a;
    int (*pb)[N][N] = &b;

    (*pa)[1][5] = 4;
    (*pb)[1][5] = 2;

    printf("%d, %d\n", (*pa)[1][5], (*pb)[1][5]);

    swap(&pb, &pa);

    printf("%d, %d\n", (*pa)[1][5], (*pb)[1][5]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would not work because what you are swapping is actually what the variables in the `swap()` function are pointing to, and not what they are pointing at. Its like if `a` was pointing at `5` and `b` was pointing at `6` in the `swap()` function, then it will make `a` point at `6` and `b` point at `5`, without changing the contents of the memory. This would mean the in the `main()` function they would be residing at the same place and would be getting pointed by the same `variable` `a` and `b` (different from the variable in `swap()`)

To swap you need to swap the contents of that memory in the `swap()` function, so that it is reflected in the `main()` function.

Recall that while doing swapping using pointers, one sends the address and actually swaps the content by dereferencing (`*p` and `*q`).